# jQuery empty input check function not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

This question has been done to death on SO and I'm really, really sorry! I've already taken the bones of the below idea from a couple of SO questions on the same theme.

All said though, I still can't get it to work as expected.

- It works OK if NONE are filled in.
- It works OK if the END input is filled in and not the others.
- It works OK if the MIDDLE input is filled in.
- If you fill in ONLY the FIRST input though, it alerts, but submits anyway?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6WpeF/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    // completed count submit handler
    $("#submit_counts_button").on('click', function () {
        window.incomplete = false;
        $('input[type=number]').each(function () {
            if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
                window.incomplete = true;
                alert('Some fields are empty');
                return false;
            } else {
                if (window.incomplete === false) {
                    $("#submit_counts_button").prop('disabled', true);
                    $("#submit_counts_button").html('Please Wait ...');
                    //$("#update_form").submit();
                }
            }
        });

    });
});
```

I'm sure it's something totally embarrassingly obvious but after a 16 hour day, I just can't see it. Any help appreciated ...

Comment: Inside `each()` it iterates over the elements, so if an input without a value is encountered it goes to the first part in the condition, and the `return false` is returning to `each()` so the iteration stops. If the first element encountered has a value, it continues to the else part of the condition and submits the form, regardless of what the other inputs contain, so the entire concept is flawed.

Comment: @adeneo With a head full of "how it should be done" (accepted answer), I can absolutely see the error of my ways now. Your explanation makes perfect sense. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pull the 'incompletion' check outside of the `.each`

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    // completed count submit handler
    $("#submit_counts_button").on('click', function () {
        window.incomplete = false;
        $('input[type=number]').each(function () {
            if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
                window.incomplete = true;
                alert('Some fields are empty');
                return false;
            }
        });

        if (window.incomplete === false) {
            $("#submit_counts_button").prop('disabled', true);
            $("#submit_counts_button").html('Please Wait ...');
            //$("#update_form").submit();
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6WpeF/6/

Comment: *shakes head in despair* I said it was going to be embarrassingly obvious ... I think I should put the keyboard down for the day. THANK YOU Michael_B.

Comment: Wow. That's so much tidier. And considerably more logical, too. Thank you very very much for taking the time; I really appreciate it. Works like a charm!

Comment: Will accept this answer shortly ... 5 more minutes apparently.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if(document.getElementById('id of input').value != ""){}
```

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer. How does this solve the OP's problem?